# What are the android-sdk and android-auth libs open source license?

Tags: android, sdk, spotify

We are working on a project that uses the following Spotify Android SDK’s

https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk
https://github.com/spotify/android-auth

Our customer needs to know what is the open source license, AGPL, GPL, LGPL, APACHE, MIT or other,  that applies for each library. I look inside document https://beta.developer.spotify.com/terms but I could not find it.

Comment: I just followed the link you posted and I found this https://beta.developer.spotify.com/legal/third-party-licenses/

Comment: But in this link it is not clear if it is AGPL, GPL, LGPL, APACHE MIT or other

Comment: It turns out that it has [no license](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/87) since this is binary only base on a 2015 post.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is that android-sdk library is not open source and android-auth is open source under Apache License 2.0. See the link below answered by the developer.

https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/415